# how to update data in diffrent table at php at once

Tags: php, html

i have database called tyneevents 3 table.
te_category  which have catID (for categoryID) and catDesc( for category description). 
te_venue which have venueID , venueName and location.
te_events which have eventID, eventTitle, eventDescription, venueID, catID, eventStartDate, eventEndDatae and eventPrice.
i have a page that called allDetails.php to edit the eventDetails.
after edited, it pass to another page called updateEventDetail.php
And here is the updateEventDetail.php code.

```
<?php   
    include "database_conn.php";


    //get all data submited
        $id         = $_GET ["eventID"];
        $title      = $_GET ["eventTitle"];
        $desc       = $_GET ["eventDescription"];
        $venue      = $_GET ["venueName"];
        $location   = $_GET ["location"];
        $category   = $_GET ["catDesc"];
        $eStart     = $_GET ["eventStartDate"];
        $eEnd       = $_GET ["eventEndDate"];
        $ePrice     = $_GET ["eventPrice"];

        $sqlUpdateEvent             = " UPDATE te_events SET
                 eventTitle         = '$title' ,
                 eventDescription   = '$desc' ,
                 catDesc            = '$category' ,
                 venueName          = '$venue' ,
                 location           = '$location' ,
                 eventStartDate     = '$eStart' ,
                 eventEndDate       = '$eEnd' , 
                 eventPrice         = '$ePrice' 
                 WHERE eventID      =  $id";

        mysqli_query ($conn , $sqlUpdateEvent)
            or die ("SQL ERROR :".mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>update mvie comfirmmation</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>update mvoie detials</h1>

<?php 

    echo "Title : $eventTitle \n";
    echo "Category : $catDesc \n";
    echo "Description : $eventDescription \n";
    echo "Venue : $venueName \n";
    echo "Location : $location \n";
    echo "Start Date : $eventStartDate \n";
    echo "End Date : $eventEndDate \n";
    echo "Price : $eventPrice \n";

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)
        echo "<p> Event update successfully </p>\n";
    else
        echo "<p> Update Fail</p>\n";

?>

<a href = "admin.php">Choose Event</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

the problem shows that

> SQL ERROR :Unknown column 'catDesc' ,'venue' 'location'  in 'field
>   list'

it seem like it cannot found the table in my database.

Comment: Not the table, but the column

Comment: catDesc column name either wrong or you have written miss spelled here please check in your db copy field name from there and paste over here

Comment: well this is simple, these columns `'catDesc' ,'venue' 'location'` do not exist in the table you are updating `te_events`...you have also said it yourself

Comment: i hope this code isn't being used in production anywhere, as without sanitising the $_GET values or using a prepared statements it is open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: how can i update 3 table data in just one sql statement?

Comment: @ManthanDave the table and column name is correct

Answer (score 0):

**te_events** only Contains  eventID, eventTitle, eventDescription, venueID, catID, eventStartDate, eventEndDatae and eventPrice.
    These catDesc' ,'venue' 'location' are in another two tables.

Comment: how can i update 3 table data in just one sql statement?